# How to print line until the first letter of the line is different (with scanner or bufferedreader)?

Tags: java, printing, while-loop, java.util.scanner

What I am trying to do is make a MATCH. I have an array with a list of numbers like this:

```
171142229
171142232
171142250
171142254
177073637
```

but there are a lot more, this is just an example and I have to find each number in all of my files, the content of the files is something like this (can't change this either and there are a lot more also each line begins either with the letter H or the I)

```
H   ZPDV    171 MO  ME  8500015847  8500015847  8500015847  8500015847  171142229   20160112    20160112    MXN 0000002978  
I   20  6CB 1               10.07   0   16  C2              9019999999171610099277  9019999999171610099277              
I   10  61  1               189.93  0   16  C2              9019999999171610099277  9019999999171610099277              
H   ZPDV    169 MO  ME  2000169 2000169 2000169 2000169 169068348   20160112    20160112    MXN 0000012213      
I   20  6CB 1               12.00   0   16  C2              7019999999169610019193  7019999999169610019193              
I   10  61  1               154.38  0   16  C2              7019999999169610019193  7019999999169610019193
```

if you notice, the first number `171142229` is found in the the first line which has an `H` at the beginning.

I want to print al the lines that have an `I` on the beginning that are below the one with the `H` and stop until the next `H`.

The program prints all the lines below, no matter what until the end of the file, then looks the next number in the list of files and do the same and so on.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] lista = CreaPVF.creaListaPendientes(); //this method creates my list of nubers
    String[] rutas = CreaPVF.recorreCarpeta();//this method has a list with the routes to my files
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) { 
        int x = 0;
        while (x < rutas.length) {                
            try{
                String[] tmp;
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(rutas[x]);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);
                String line=scanner.nextLine();
                do{                    
                    tmp=scanner.nextLine().split("\t");
                    if (lista[i].equals(tmp[9])) {
                        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                            do{                              
                                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                            }while(tmp[0].equals("I"));
                        }
                    }

                }while(scanner.hasNext() ) ;      
                scanner.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {

            }
            x++;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `line` is unused, and is taking up a Scanner.nextLine(), you are effectively ignoring the first line of the file with this.

Next, in order to get your loop working correctly, you're gonna want to move the initialization of tmp outside of the loop.  This ensures that no lines are skipped.

Finally, you need to update tmp inside the loop, and check it for starting character before displaying the line.

```
            // extract the next line from the stream
            tmp=scanner.nextLine().split("\t");

            do{
                // check if our number is in that line
                if (lista[i].equals(tmp[9])) {
                    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                        do{
                            tmp=scanner.nextLine();
                            if(tmp[0].equals("I")) {
                                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp));
                            }
                        }while(tmp[0].equals("I"));
                    }
                }

            }while(scanner.hasNext() ) ;
```

I've used `Arrays.toString(tmp);` here because it's the quickest way to show the result.  You might want to consider reading every line into a string, and splitting it into another variable.  That way you retain the string for display later.